# Rails form_for help, login page not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
<% form_for @User do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_messages %>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :username %>
        <%= f.text_field :password %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :password %>
        <%= f.password_field :password %>
    </p>

    <%= f.submit 'Login' %>
<% end %>
```

I'm getting the error:

```
undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class
```

my user_controller.rb is:

```
def login
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you shouldn't use `@User`, as in ruby convention, upper case referes to constants, while variables use lower cases. So better `@user` instead of `@User`. (Of course using `@User` the program should run...)

The error telling you that you passed a `nil` object to the `form_for`. It seems that you didn't initialized the `@User` object, and so it's `nil`.

```
def login
  @User = User.new
end
```

This should be OK, tell me if not.